# Cambiar estilo flexbox según cantidad de botones dentro de un div

Tags: css3, scss, flexbox

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un div el cual cuenta con 3 botones, estos tres botones deben extenderse en total por todo el div, es decir como si tuvieran un width: 100%. Solo que esto se esta logrando con flex: 1;
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ahora bien necesito que cuando se elimine un botón de estos ese flex:1; se ignore, es decir que se vea de la siguiente manera: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Puede parecer un poco tonto, pero es algo que me están pidiendo, se que por js se puede lograr algo, solo que me están obligando a utilizar solo flex, alguna idea de como solucionar este problema.

Aquí esta un ejemplo de código:

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  .botones{ 
     //flex: 1;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <button class="botones">Boton 1</button>
  <button class="botones">Boton 2</button>
  <button class="botones boton_especial">Boton 3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: En tu segunda imagen (donde describes gráficamente lo que quieres) veo que tienes los botones a la derecha del contenedor, que es exactamente la distribución de los botones en el contenedor que tienes ahora en tu snippet. Con ello es que necesito preguntar: Supongamos que de tus tres botones elimino el primero, ¿cuál es la distribución que quieres que tengan los otros dos botones en el contenedor?

Comment: En tus dos ejemplos tienes tres botones, si elimino un botón del primer ejemplo deberían quedar dos, sin embargo siguen habiendo tres. ¿estás seguro que el requerimiento es _eliminar uno de los botones_?

Comment: Me temo que con CSS solo no puedes hacer eso. El CSS no accede al HTML, no "sabe" cuantos botones tienes, solo aplica los estilos al selector correspondiente